# Tab bar at top and bottom

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

I would like to develop a ipad apps which has a menu at the top of the screen as well as at the bottom.

There are four buttons on the top of the screen, and there are 10+ buttons at the bottom tab bar, which can be scrolled horizontally.

How can I write the root view controller as a framework for this operation?

Should I customize the UIViewController class or UITabBarViewController?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Sorry for being unclear. Let me restate my question.

Actually my app will have the following hierarchy.

[image]

'Front Page' is simply a page (view controller) for user to choose language. After choosing the language, 'Menu Page' view controller is displayed.

Starting from Menu page and ALL view controllers (VC) in below, the page layout is something like this.

[image]

As you can see, there are top menu and bottom menu. Clicking on the buttons the app will quickly jump to the corresponding view controller (3rd level in the tree, VC1,VC2,VC3 etc) . And for every view, there is a BACK button on every page, clicking which will back to the parent view controller.

I was thinking to implement this by using a tab bar view controller and a navigation view controller but I still do not have a clear idea how to implement this.

Or maybe should I just use the navigation view controller and hide the top tool bar except the back button, and display an overlay UIView as menu which is on top of all other UIViews.

Can somebody help me? Thanks.

Since this is the outermost container for my app I hope to do it properly at start..

Sorry for my long question.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to develop a framework for this logic .You need to create Manager, ViewController, View, DAO ,Model and other classes according to your needs.

I assume you want to add the buttons dynamically to the tabbar (and if it scrollable , it must be a scrollview).You can use Toolbar for upper view but then it won't be in sync with the bottom-view(visually).In that case you will have to create your own customized views to look like a tabbar.

The manager will basically keep a track of all the buttons and different states of events and action on the views and the same information can be accessed via a static method form the viewcontroller.

Well you have not detailed on your needs , so it's difficult to predict the entire architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have updated my question hope that it is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need a container view controller to manage selection of VC's 1-4.

> clicking which will back to the parent view controller

Parent view controller is used to mean the container vc in a container view controller scheme - I'm not sure that's what you mean in this comment. Where exactly does the back button go?

See this link for more info about container VC's.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

You should be able to embed a tab bar controller in the content view of the container VC. *Should be able to* but it might be really buggy if there is a lot of communication between the child vc's.

The hard part is the back button. Basically it must be a button that goes back to VC 1-4 depending on which section you are in. The easiest way to do it is to make sure that when you cycle view controllers, pass the back button information as to which VC is the current child so it knows which VC to navigate to when you press it.